# How do I suggest a fix to an error in the FAQs?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

My specific note is that an FAQ answer talks about US and EU patents and using a tag like [EU12345]. There are EPO patents, not EU patents. The numbers start with EP not EU.

Answer (score 1):

This change has been made. Thank you for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: In the EPO the prefix of a patent number is EP not EPO. Now that google patents includes EPO documents this is easy to see in the results of most searches.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks for catching that! I fixed it. Let me know if there are any other errors.